# Polulating pickerView with weight or length data

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to make a pickerView where user can choose his/her weight... in Swift 2.2 I was thinking to make a Range like this:

```
var weightList: [Int] = Array(40...140)
var weight = weightList.map{ $0.map(String.init) }
```

But this is not accepted: Instance member 'weight' cannot be used on type ViewController

How to make a range of numbers into an Array? Or is there an other solution for populating weight (number and kg) en length (in cm) in a pickerView?

Comment: Are you trying to get an Array of type String?

Comment: Yes Array type of String to use it in a pickerView or is it possible to use a Int in a pickerView?

Comment: It has been quite  while since I've last used a picker view. But I think it would be similar as using a table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a `[String]` using a range, you can use:

```
var weight = (40...140).map { String($0) }
```

Comment: Thnx! I was close but don't really understand the new swift syntax ;-) Learning

Comment: You're welcome. Once you learn more about higher order functions it's a lot of fun! :p As for your second question, I think it should be possible but it's not very clear to me what exactly you want.

Comment: I've a lot of pickerViews from languages to lenght about a person.... So I want to populating weight (number and kg) en lenght (in cm) in a pickerView